# my application works on the emulator but not on my device

Tags: android, api, emulation

Excuse me for any grammatical errors.

I'm having a strange problem: My application works fine on the emulator (emulator of a Nexus 5X API 25) but on my phone (Nexus 5X Android 7.1.2 Beta Program) it crashes.

The strange thing is that on another phone with Android 7.1.1, this application doesn't crashes, so I'm sure that the problem is something related to API or something like this.

Some ideas?

The error when the application crashes:

```
> 02-26 18:21:13.515 I/Timeline(791): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.application time:718314
02-26 18:21:13.525 I/ActivityManager(549): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.application/.MainActivity bnds=[123,128][240,271]} from pid 791
02-26 18:21:13.616 I/ActivityManager(549): Start proc com.application for activity com.application/.MainActivity: pid=4157 uid=10064 gids={50064, 1028, 1015, 3003}
02-26 18:21:13.716 D/ActivityThread(4157): handleBindApplication:com.application
02-26 18:21:13.786 E/AndroidRuntime(4157): Process: com.application, PID: 4157
02-26 18:21:13.786 E/AndroidRuntime(4157): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.application-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.application-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-26 18:21:13.786 E/AndroidRuntime(4157): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.application-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.application-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
02-26 18:21:13.796 W/ActivityManager(549):   Force finishing activity com.application/.MainActivity
02-26 18:21:14.496 W/ActivityManager(549): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{420245f8 u0 com.application/.MainActivity t15 f}
02-26 18:21:15.417 I/ActivityManager(549): Process com.application (pid 4157) has died.
```

I can post my main code if this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instant Run tries to do hot swapping of your code; this causes the application class to be moved.

To disable Instant Run Go to File --> Settings--> Build,Execution,Deployment -->Instant Run ---> uncheck "Enable instant run"

Comment: Thank you very much.
Can I know what was the problem? Why Instant Run gives me this problem?